# Intermittent null data returned by memcache on get method

Tags: php, memcached

I'm running memcached and my application is using the php libmemcached.

The code itself is a simple check key exists, if not pull fresh from mysql database with an 'x' amount of expiry time.

I have an array of data I pull from mysql which is returned via another method as an array - this is stored into memcached under the key 'menudata_array'. Everything was fine until I noticed sometimes the menudata was being returned from the caching method as null or empty???

The only bit of info I have is that when the menudata is returned empty|null, the period of error is equal to the expiry timeout of 120 seconds ?? After which the next request for data is returned ok.

I'm sure i've misunderstood something here!

The code is as follows:

```
function getMenuData()
{

$menudata_array = array(); //init an empty array

$memcache = getMemcache();  //method returns an instance of memcache (global) or false is failure

if($memcache)
{
    //get from memcache
    $menudata_array = $memcache->get('menudata_array');

     //make sure something was returned
     if($menudata_array === false)
     {

     $menudata_array = generate_menu_array(); // get from mysql db
     $expire_seconds = 120;
     $refresh = $memcache->add('menudata_array', $menudata_array, false, $expire_seconds);
     if($refresh === false)
    {
    //key already exists so replace instead ...
    $memcache->replace('menudata_array', $menudata_array, false, $expire_seconds);
    }

 } 

}
else
{
    //memcache not available|down... get from mysql db instead
    $menudata_array = generate_menu_array();

}


//i added this line to track when this problem was happening ...
if(!$menudata_array || count($menudata_array)<=0)
{
         logError();
}

return $menudata_array;

}
```

Any help/pointers appreciated!

Comment: Instead of using `if (!add(...)) { replace(...); }`, you can simply use `set(...)` and that will either create a new entry or overwrite the old one.  Not an answer but it would remove an unnecessary complexity from your code.

Comment: The code you have there looks pretty much right for a standard time-based caching pattern, and works for me with simulated `generate_menu_array`, `getMemcache` and `logError` methods - `logError` is never called.

Comment: Hi leftclickben, I used the add/replace because there was a note on php docs of possible errors happening in multiple server setup where set is used on an existing key (i'm not using multi-server but just in case)

Comment: The only weak link I can see if memcache isn't the problem is the (generate_menu_array) method - but as that uses mysql, I can't see why mysql would return nothing sometimes ??? really weird!